# spatstat or R alternative to ESRI Point Density Tool?

Tags: r, spatstat

I am trying to figure if it is best possible way to replicate ESRI [point density](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/point-density.htm) tool in `spatstat` R package.

I got bunch of archaeological sites location with associated size and would like to compute surface with hectare per square km (magnitude-per-unit area as in ERSI tool) to track changes through time.
I used spatstat `density.ppp`  (with  ppp rescaled to km) function to create point intensity per unit area surfaces, but I am not sure whether I should be using either `weights` argument in `density.ppp` or `smooth.ppp` or just use any kind of focal analysis function to get the hectare per km2 surface, which I understand ESRI point density tool is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `spatstat` function `density.ppp` with the `weights` argument giving the associated size of each site. That is,

```
density(X, weights=w)
```

where `X` is a point pattern object of class `ppp`, and `w` is a numeric vector of length equal to `npoints(X)` containing the associated sizes of the sites in the same order.

See page 173-174 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org)

Comment: perfect, now its all clear to me, also I checked that the sum of density values is equal to total area of sites. thank you!